# WPF Efficient Bitmap render management

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, bitmap, render

I am implementing a security camera. I have the following methods, lets call them for simplicity:

**capture**(...)// captures the frame from the camera, frame used by the following methods:

**comparetemplates**(...)//if it detects any motion it triggers the following method:

**detection**(...)// applies haarcascade detection and recognition through EmguCv;

Basically I capture() the frame, check the boolean comparetemplates() and render the captured frame with detection() applied on it.

The Problem:
**capture**() renders to the screen real time in 30fps, however, the other methods require more time.
All operations are made with **System.Drawing.Bitmap** and conversions to wpf Source for rendering.

The Question:
I am willing to sacrifice real time rendering for a smooth, 30 fps rendering delayed by up to 6 seconds. I am not asking necesarily for code, but for the actual principle to call the methods and apply System delays or anything (threads etc).
Thank you.

Comment: so here the delay between after capture image to motion detection ?

Comment: The delay is caused by the motion detection and detection methods, because they need to do lots of image processing, capture is real time.

Comment: i think you need to implement queue to solve this problem ..

Comment: Are you applying the detection to every single frame? I expect the effect would be around the same if you only do it every 15 frames or so.

Comment: I am applying comparetemplates() to every frame, and detection to every frame that is worth applying detection(if comparetemplates returns true). I need to see every fps out of those 30 because it is a SECURITY camera, and every motion should be captured and analyzed.